# Google Mock: How to test this code?

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I wrote the following piece of code to test `Xyz::xyz_func` by mocking `Abc::abc_func` using Google Mock.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

using namespace std;
using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::Return;

class Abc
{
    public:
        virtual ~Abc() {}

        virtual bool abc_func(int arg)  = 0;
};

class MockAbc : public Abc
{
    public:
        virtual ~MockAbc() { }

        MOCK_METHOD1(abc_func,  bool(int arg));
};

class AbcImpl : public Abc
{
    public:
        virtual bool abc_func(int arg)
        {
            cout << arg << " :: " << __FILE__ << " :: " << __LINE__ << endl;
            return true;
        }
};

class Xyz : public AbcImpl
{
    public:
        virtual ~Xyz() {}
        virtual bool xyz_func()
        {
            AbcImpl obj;
            return obj.abc_func(1);
        }
};

TEST(AbcTest, func_success)
{
    MockAbc *mock = new MockAbc();

    EXPECT_CALL(*mock,  abc_func(_)).WillOnce(Return(true));

    Xyz test;

    EXPECT_TRUE(test.xyz_func());

    delete mock;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

But i get the below error. I want to know how we can tell Xyz class to call mock of abc_func instead of actual implementation. Could you please help me.

```
1 :: ./gmock_test.cpp :: 30
./gmock_test.cpp:50: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*mock, abc_func(_))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a mock object of type `MockAbc` but you never use it. From your code it appears that you're expecting the `MockAbc` instance you create to automagically replace the `AbcImpl` object that you explicitly create in `Xyz::xyz_func`.

What you need to be doing instead is using [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) to allow the object used by `xyz_func` to be specified at runtime.

You don't need `Xyz` to inherit from `AbcImpl` or `Abc`.

---

Two potential solutions:

```
class Xyz {
public:
    explicit Xyz(Abc& obj) : 
        obj(&) {
    }

    virtual bool xyz_func() {
        return obj->abc_func(1);
    }
private:
    Abc* obj;
};
```

or

```
class Xyz {
public:
    virtual bool xyz_func(Abc& obj) {
        return obj->abc_func(1);
    }
};
```